# WCF, StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm getting StackOverflowException at this line. I'm kind of new to WCF but as far as i can see it's not called in an infinity loop. Well i was hoping someone here could shed some light on this problem.

```
 get { return LevStad; }
```

The code.

```
 // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
    [OperationContract]
    Kund GetDataUsingDataContract(Kund kund);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
[DataContract]
public class Kund
{
    int iD;
    string fornamn = "";
    string efterNamn = "";
    string telefon = "";
    string boAdress = "";
    string boPostnummer = "";
    string boStad = "";
    string boLand = "";
    string levAdress = "";
    string levPostnummer = "";
    string levStad = "";
    string levLand = "";

    [DataMember]
    public int ID
    {
        get { return iD; }
        set { iD = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Fornamn
    {
        get { return fornamn; }
        set { fornamn = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string EfterNamn
    {
        get { return efterNamn; }
        set { efterNamn = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Telefon
    {
        get { return telefon; }
        set { telefon = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string BoAdress
    {
        get { return boAdress; }
        set { boAdress = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string BoPostnummer
    {
        get { return boPostnummer; }
        set { boPostnummer = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string BoStad
    {
        get { return boStad; }
        set { boStad = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string BoLand
    {
        get { return boLand; }
        set { BoLand = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string LevAdress
    {
        get { return levAdress; }
        set { levAdress = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string LevPostnummer
    {
        get { return levPostnummer; }
        set { levPostnummer = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string LevStad
    {
        get { return LevStad; }
        set { levStad = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string LevLand
    {
        get { return levLand; }
        set { levLand = value; }
    }
}

    public class Service : SQLBase, IService
    {
        public Service() : base()
        {

        }
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
        public Kund GetDataUsingDataContract(Kund kund)
        {
            kund = new Kund();
            SqlCommand SQLCom = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Kund.ID, Förnamn, Efternamn, Telefon, Adress, Postnummer, Stad, Land 
FROM Webbshop.dbo.Kund INNER JOIN Webbshop.dbo.Adress ON Kund.BoAdress = Adress.ID");
            SQLCom.Connection = DatabaseConnection;
            SQLCom.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = SQLCom.ExecuteReader(); 
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                kund.ID = (int) rdr[0];
                kund.Fornamn = rdr[1].ToString().Trim();
                kund.EfterNamn = rdr[2].ToString().Trim();
                kund.Telefon = rdr[3].ToString().Trim();
                kund.BoAdress = rdr[4].ToString().Trim();
                kund.BoPostnummer = rdr[5].ToString().Trim();
                kund.BoStad = rdr[6].ToString().Trim();
                //kund.BoLand = rdr[7].ToString().Trim();
                //kund.LevAdress = rdr[8].ToString();
                //kund.LevPostnummer = rdr[9].ToString();
                //kund.LevStad = rdr[10].ToString();
                //kund.LevLand = rdr[11].ToString();
            }
            SQLCom.Connection.Close();
            return kund;
        }
    }

public class SQLBase
{
    protected static SqlConnection DatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection();
    public SQLBase()
    {
        DatabaseConnection.ConnectionString =
           "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Webbshop;Integrated Security=True";
    }
}

Kund kund = null;// = new Kund();
using (ServiceReference.ServiceClient wcfClient = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient())
{
    kund = wcfClient.GetDataUsingDataContract(kund);
}
```

Comment: If you want people to read your code and try to help, please consider removing the irrelevant 99%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the capitalization. It should return the variable:

```
get { return levStad; }
```

Right now, it's returning itself, which calls `get`, which returns itself... stack overflow.

---

You'll also have an issue with `BoLand`; `set` will set itself, which will call `set`... again, capitalization:

```
public string BoLand
{
    get { return boLand; }
    set { boLand = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public string LevStad
{
    get { return LevStad; }
    set { levStad = value; }
}
```

There is your problem. It's recursing on LevStad.

ie. You get LevStad and it tries to get the property LevStad, which tries to get the property LevStad. And so it goes on until the call-stack overflows.

Just make it set the field instead (C# is case-sensitive).

```
public string LevStad
{
    get { return levStad; }
    set { levStad = value; }
}
```

You will have a similar problem on the set of BoLand.

```
public string BoLand
{
    get { return boLand; }
    set { BoLand = value; }
}
```

Comment: That's actually another similar error. The one OP asked about is LevStad